# CORs request with flask api - Jquery POST request results in OPTIONs

Tags: jquery, cors, sinatra, flask-restful, flask-cors

I have a flask API to control an immersion heater device.

https://github.com/timcknowles/anovapi_backend/blob/master/anova.py

This is on my localhost server and it responds correctly to JQuery POST requests on the same domain e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#start").click(function() {

                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'post',
                      url: 'http://192.168.0.13:5000/start',
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      success: function(data) {
                         $("#message").html(data);
                      }


$("#settemp").click(function() {

                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'post',
                      contentType: 'application/json',
                      url: ' http://192.168.0.13:5000/temp',
                      data: JSON. stringify ({"temp":"50"}),
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(data) {
                         $("#message").html(data);
                      }
            });
```

However I wanted to build a sinatra client app on a different server

https://github.com/timcknowles/anovapi_frontend/blob/master/main.rb

to interact with the same api. The jquery is identical and works fine for the START call however for the TEMP call it doesn't work

In the developer console of firefox I can see it has OPTIONS instead of a POST request (response 200).

Initially I had cross domain problems with all my api jQuery requests and I thought I had resolved these by adding the flask cors extension to my api.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors

I don't understand why the temp call isn't working but the others are. I suspect it is because I am sending data in the form of temperature values.

Any advice hugely appreciated.

Comment: What's the error in the second call?

Comment: It doesn't seen to give an error it just doesn't work

Comment: Trap the error function in your js or see what the result of the call is in your browser developer tools.

Comment: In fact using the chrome console this is the error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4567' is therefore not allowed access. Interestingly I can now see on chrome that the other requests e.g. start also generate an error XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.13:5000/start. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4567' is therefore not allowed access they still work and switch the device on/off

Comment: You do have an extra space here: JSON. stringify

Comment: @RobertMoskal I have removed the space JSON.stringify but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize CORS() for Flask to work.

Try putting this on [line 12 of your python server](https://github.com/timcknowles/anovapi_backend/blob/19d0cdb2b0884cbd2036a630501f89db5582ec18/anova.py#L12):

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

You might also get away with just `CORS(app)` (I've never used Flask so I'm unsure).

See the [Flask docs](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) under Simple Usage for more information.